# Environment variable doesn't get populated before the pre-request Script

Tags: rest, environment-variables, postman

[Postman] I'm needing to hash the url of my Get request, before it gets submitted.  I have a {{BaseUrl}} environment variable that I've set in the url, but I'm finding that when I call, in the pre-request script, request.url (to retrieve the url), the enviro variable isn't populated w/ the value I've set for it.  It basically responds with "{{BaseUrl}}" in the url.

Are environment variables not available till after the pre-request script?  Assuming no, any other ways of achieving this, without hard coding the base url, being we have multiple environments?

url:

```
{{BaseUrl}}/Web.Api/blah/blah?startDate=1-1-2015
```

pre-request script:

```
// create hash
var origUrl = request.url;
var split = origUrl.split("://");
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(split[1], "5G6F4G7U467-546F-R6G7-7HIH-5G7HUR67HI6");
var base64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Authentication", "999:" + base64);
```

Resolution:
I resorted to calling postman.getEnvironmentVariable in the pre-request script.

Comment: Environment variables should be available in pre request script as well. Where are you setting the baseUrl variable? I'm unable to see that in your script.

Comment: I've worked around this by using postman.getEnvironmentVariable("Baseurl") and combining that value with the rest of the url and then getting the hash that way.  It'll be a hassle to split the url string and what not, but it's doable.

That environment variable is already set (hard coded) as we have 4 or so environments that have different base urls.

Perhaps this could be an enhancement to make environment variables available/populated when running request.url in the pre-request script.